# Large loop with performance problems

Tags: php, loops

I've got two large arrays, where second one is dependant on first one.

Categories, about 40 rows, Items about 40.000 per Category.

1. I need to go through every Category - get Category object.
2. Get from database Items for Category.
3. Compare Items if there share value of specific attribute

using PHP 7.1 I'want to get without O(n)^n solution if possible.

```
private function removeOverlap()
{
    $categories = $this->getCategories();

    foreach($categories as $category)
    {
        $items = $this->getItems($category);

        foreach($items as $item)
        {
            foreach($items as $sibling)
            {
                if($item === $sibling) continue;

                $this->fixOverlap($item, $sibling)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm looking for performance upgrade, because this takes literally forever.

Comment: I would suggest using generators ... Are you using any framework or any ORM at all ??

Comment: Assuming both categories and items are stored in database, better use DB engine to perform this job.

Make sure table fields are optimized as well. Index what is necessary.

Comment: Maybe You could return categories with items in one call to database. Depending on Your db relations.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to question.** Note that `foreach` iterates over all records every time. You should unset what records you've already parsed.

```
foreach($items as $key => $item) 
{ 
    foreach($items as $sibling) 
    { 
        if($item === $sibling) continue; 
        $this->fixOverlap($item, $sibling); // not sure what this method does.
     } 

     unset($items[$key]); // unset keys which were previously parsed
}
```

I'm not sure what you're aming for with your code, but in case it's just a search through items for duplicates, I'd use `array_unique()`: http://php.net/array_unique

```
$filtered = array_unique($items);
```

---

**Good practice.** Using PHP will take a lifetime. Not just because it requires large CPU consumption, but also because it takes time for MySQL server to return all `categories * 40k` records.

I believe you should use optimised SQL queries instead. Databases perform these tasks much faster than PHP itself. Here's a demo:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM items WHERE items.category = 'category1';
```

This will automatically return all distinct records from database for `category1`. If you use indexes for `items` table, the search will be enchanted.